can not import tftrainer from transformers
I try to train a GPT2 model on my own data
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
from transformers import TextDataset, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from transformers import TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments

but I get the error "cannot import name 'TFTrainer' from 'transformers'"
I tried to change the version of transformers but I still experienced the same problem.
I also tried
from tftrainer import TrainArgument, Trainer
from transformers.trainer_tf import TFTrainer


TFTrainer is a separate package that transformers, so you need to install it separately and do:
from tftrainer import Trainer, TrainArgument
This is because TFTrainer is no longer supported by transformers.
You could try to install an older version of transformers which still supports it, though.

Can I Know which Version Of transformers support it
